# Show Autohide Message with Sound in Jquery and HTML 5

Tags: jquery, html, audio, callback

I need to show a list of n messages alerts, but I have problem with callbacks!

My div is #foo and is Display:none

For each message in messagelist:

1) Append to div (for example "Patient Brown Peter")

2) Play a sound (audio like dorrbell)

3) Show div for 5 seconds

4) Autohide

Thanks!

EDIT:This code sound work but not the text inside DIV.

```
        $.each(dataResponse, function (key, val) {

            //$('#UltimosTurnos').append('<li id="' + key + '">' + val.Mensaje + ' ' + val.Ubicacion + '</li>');

            $('#Llamada').fadeIn('slow', function () {
                // play your audio
                $('#Llamada').append(val.Mensaje);
                audio.play();
            }).delay(5000).fadeOut('slow');

        }); //-- Fin each
```

Comment: Can we see the code you already have?

Comment: Yes! I updated whit code now.